# How to make a list like 1.1, 1.2 with Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I tried everything and this just doesn't seem to be possible anymore?

It can do

```
1.1 Text
2.1 Text
```

but not

```
1.1 Text
1.2 Text
```

Answer (score 4):

- **enter numbered list**

  > [image: 5]
- **select [Edit prefix and suffix...]**

  > [image: 5]
- **type in the prefix `1.`**

  > [image: 6]
- **done**

  > [image: 5]

Answer (score 2):

1. Add numbered list.

[image]

2. Enter list items and select them.

[image]

3. Press increase indent.

[image]

4. Done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Format - Bullets & Numbering - List Options - Edit Prefix and suffix